# Is there any Annotation Processing Library for Network Connection Check in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, connectivity, annotation-processing

My application constantly does API requests and I am checking connection status with `ConnectivityManager`. If it's connected then requesting for a data from the server, if not showing an error dialog that says *Not connected to internet*.

Well above method is manageable, but I wanted to have much more cleaner method for checking connectivity status and was thinking of Annotation Processing Library. Something like if I put `@RequiresConnection` annotation on my method that requests connection, then if it's not connected then it will automatically fire an error dialog with a retry button invoking the function that didn't get executed. So whenever user pressed a `Retry` button of dialog, it again tries to execute that function?

I am thinking of doing this annotation processing myself, but if it's already out there with I wanted to use it. Is there any such library?

Answer (score 0):

With Retrofit 2, you can use an OkHttp Interceptor implementation to check for network connectivity ahead of sending the request. If no network, throw an exception or Toast an error.